# Bootstrap 2.3.2 modal and screen readers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a site that uses Bootstrap 2.3.2 and it appears that the Bootstrap modal dialogs are pretty much invisible to screen readers. 
Is there anything that I can do to make the screen reader see the contents of my bootstrap 2.3.2 modal ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to checkout what PayPal changed for Bootstrap3 to make it accessible: https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin  You probably can back port the changes to Bootstrap2. Here's another library that might be helpful.  It highlights the accessibility issues on the page: https://khan.github.io/tota11y/